# Remove just a field on Firestore REST API

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to delete a single field of a document via PATCH method in Firebase Firestore REST API but I can't find a [value](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1beta1/Value) (or method) that represents "remove this field" like in Firebase Realtime database exist `undefined` value to do that. Do you know how to achieve that?

Answer (score 5):

The [Firestore REST API documentation for the patch method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.databases.documents/patch) accepts a [DocumentMask](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1beta1/DocumentMask) object.  It has the following effect:

> If the document exists on the server and has fields not referenced in
>   the mask, they are left unchanged. Fields referenced in the mask, but
>   not present in the input document, are deleted from the document on
>   the server.

So, your mask should contain the fields to delete, and you should not give them a value in the request body.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, your answer works fine but finally the behavior of patch method not work as I expected.